# c# how to write to a text file from list box as a result of proccess

Tags: c#, file, text, export

I'm trying to add x and y data in text file like all the x result line by line and y results next to x for example ; 40,281516651,1,17956575 . But in this codes overwriting the results to many times because of the `foreach`.

```
        double z, d, x, k, y;
        d = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);

        for (double i = 0; i <= 90; i++)
        {
            k = Math.PI / 180;
            z = Math.Tan((i / 2 + 45) * k);
            x = (d / 3.141) * (Math.Sin(Math.PI * i / 180) - Math.Log(z));
            y = d / 3.141 * (Math.Cos((Math.PI * i) / 180) + (3.141 / 2));  
            listBox2.Items.Add(x);
            listBox1.Items.Add(y);
            listBox3.Items.Add(z);
            const string sPath = @"C:\Users\NET\Desktop\deneme.txt";
            StreamWriter SaveFile = new StreamWriter(sPath);   
            foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
            {
                SaveFile.WriteLine(item);
                foreach (var a in listBox2.Items)
                {
                    SaveFile.WriteLine(a);
                }                     
            }                             
            SaveFile.Close();                        
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yout `i`should be `int`, not `double`. And **please** fix your formating, indentation, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//fill the listBoxes
for (double i = 0; i <= 90; i++)
{
   k = Math.PI / 180;
   z = Math.Tan((i / 2 + 45) * k);

   x = (d / 3.141) * (Math.Sin(Math.PI * i / 180) - Math.Log(z));
   y = d / 3.141 * (Math.Cos((Math.PI * i) / 180) + (3.141 / 2)); 

   listBox2.Items.Add(x);
   listBox1.Items.Add(y);
   listBox3.Items.Add(z);
}

// write the text file
const string sPath = @"C:\Users\NET\Desktop\deneme.txt";
using(StreamWriter SaveFile = new StreamWriter(sPath))
{   
  for (int i=0; i<listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
  {
    string line = String.Format("{0},{1}", listBox1.Items[i], listBox2.Items[i]);
    SaveFile.WriteLine(line);
  }          
}
```

Comment: I separeted them already tried it,but than x and y doesn't go side by side,i want to do like x results line by line and next to x result to be y result like this; 
40,9184972938555,1,76730822130716E-15

Comment: the reason to add thoose x and y results to listbox to see that the formule is working or not. My point was the proccess the x and y variables and export them as a text file couse after i export them i'll use them in solidworks.

Comment: @enigmad87 I don't understand *doesn't work* ?! can you give an example? give a range of `x` and `y` values and how you want them to be written in the text file

Comment: the codes not working i perform your foreach a for loop and change to 'i'  as 'a' couse i was using. after that changes error is savefile is already using.

Comment: sorry that was a syntax error I changed it to for loop, don't change `i` leave it as it is now, can you try it now?

Comment: it's working know thank you so much thank you so muchhhhhhh :)))))

Comment: :) my pleasure, next time you should know how to structure your question better in order to get good response

Comment: i'm just new in this site sorry for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't **nest** your loops, but haver them one after the next:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= 90; i++)
    {
        ...
        listBox2.Items.Add(x);
        listBox1.Items.Add(y);
        listBox3.Items.Add(z);
    }
    ...
    foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
    {
        SaveFile.WriteLine(item);
    }
    foreach (var a in listBox2.Items)
    {
        SaveFile.WriteLine(a);
    }
```